# restful API in android via retrofit approach

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I'm trying to fetch data from certain API by creating a retrofit object and a call object in the onCreate method.

I expect to get new data each change in orientation or intent navigation by the basic assumption, that the onCreate is invoked again over and over.

for some reason, the data is just fetched once and not updated later on.

maybe the problem is not about the way I use the API rather something else, but I would like to know if it's also an accepted way that can work?, because I've heard that the standard approach would be by creating a service.

Comment: Have you checked what's happening with a debugger?

Comment: Have you tried moving the request to onResume? OnCreate is only called when the Activity is killed, not paused

Comment: It helped, I forgot the activity cycle. Thanks!